# 403 Forbiden when publish module to npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to publish a module but always get an error. Please help to check
This is my error

```
npm notice 
npm notice   remove-null@1.0.0
npm notice === Tarball Contents === 
npm notice 435B index.js    
npm notice 178B package.json
npm notice === Tarball Details === 
npm notice name:          remove-null                             
npm notice version:       1.0.0                                   
npm notice package size:  467 B                                   
npm notice unpacked size: 613 B                                   
npm notice shasum:        be0e9f07c9f43c01959de7b5a623d9be6c358aba
npm notice integrity:     sha512-vXiTrxXk5H0sf[...]Cqo3wBwnLX1Lg==
npm notice total files:   2                                       
npm notice 
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/remove-null - Forbidden
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dungva/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T04_11_35_573Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug 'npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830477/how-to-debug-npm-err-403-in-most-cases-you-or-one-of-your-dependencies-are-re)

Answer (score 0):

1. create an organization.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElvDO.png)
2. invite a member, such as yourself.
3. login the email of the member, accept and verify the invitation above.
4. npm login and publish your module.