# Unable to create react app using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I tried `npx create-react-app` command on terminal but I'm getting the following error:-

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

npm -v is 6.14.11
node -v is v12.21.0
Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug 'npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830477/how-to-debug-npm-err-403-in-most-cases-you-or-one-of-your-dependencies-are-re)

Comment: Also, possibly: [npm behind a proxy fails with status 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773509/npm-behind-a-proxy-fails-with-status-403)

Comment: I am connected to VPN.. this might be the issue

Comment: If the VPN proves to be the issue, please consider [self-closing your question as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/is-it-possible-to-mark-my-own-question-as-duplicate-of-another).

Comment: After removing VPN too.. it shows the same error

Comment: What is the version of your app in the package.json ?

Answer (score 1):

Just Try to use `sudo npx create-react-app` if still not working
Test this solution

`npm init`
`npm install create-react-app`
`npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: How would `sudo` resolve a a 403 error coming from npm?

Comment: @Boaz oh no i thought it was a folder error not npm 403 i didnt see it ( sry )

Comment: No need to apologize :)